# java - connecting interface to class member

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, implements

Say I have an interface A and a class B that implements it.
Now, I also have some class C which extends class D (which means that it can't also extends B) but I also need there the functionality of interface A.

The solution I know is to have a member of A instantiated by B in C (which will implement A) and when implementing the functions of A call the matching function from the member of A.

Is there any way to create some connection between the functions of A and the member inside C? (so that java will know that every time it needs to call a function from A it will directly go and and run the matching function from the A member without me needing to write the code for it for every function of A)

A big thank you is waiting to each one of the helpers...

Comment: Design problems shouldn't be approached in this way. Show us how A,B C and D are related.

Comment: If you are bothered only by the manual labor of writing the forwarding calls, your IDE (assuming that you use one) will probably have functionality to help you.

Comment: _"The solution I know is to have a member of B in C"_. You should have a member of type A in C so that C only depends on the interface A and not the implementation B.

Comment: @JaeHeonLee I'm looking for this option so that if I'll need to add some functionality to A in the future - I won't need to change the code of C....

Comment: @TheLostMind Well, the problem is like this.
I have two classes X and Y that extends X. Those are "of the shelf" classes so I can't touch them.
I've created a class Z that extends X.
what I'm looking for is a way to create a new class K that will extends Y but will also get each new function I'll add to Y in the future (without the need to make changes to the code of that new class K).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As already stated delegation must be implemented manually.

Having said that, you have a few options to simplify this: If you're working with Eclipse, select *Source|Generate Delegate Methods...* and select your member variable. Eclipse will then generate all the delegate methods for you. I don't know about other IDEs, but I would be surprised, if NetBeans et al. would not have a similar feature.

Another option, if you actually want to decorate existing collection classes, consider Google Guava's [Google Guava's Collection Helpers](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained).

Last, but not least, you could consider restructing your code and decorate your classes using Advices. Advices stem from Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) and typically use a proxying mechanism to enrich original target classes. This is a rather advanced technique, but if you are determined to go down this road, have a look at [Spring's AOP support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop).

Answer (score 0):

So to sum up, here is your class hierarchies:

```java
package common;
public interface A 
{
  void doStuff();
}
```

```java
package commom.impl;
public class B implements A 
{
  void doStuff() {}
}
```

```java
package real.service;
public class D 
{
  void doSomeRealStuff() {}
}
```

```java
package real.service;
public class C extends D 
{
  void doSomeRealStuffForGood() {}
}
```

*Assuming that each class is declared in its own source file.*

Just to recall from the OP, I assume you need `B` stuff in `C` and not really `A` stuff. Because `A` is nothing but a contract and you need then the real implemting class to be fetched inside your `C` class in order to call the declared methods on.

In such a case, you may need to use the ***Inversion of Responsability*** approach, so that you declare an instacne of type `B` inside your `C` clas then you layer each method from `B` with a one having the same signature and that do nothing but delegate the real call to the instance member:

```java
package real.service;

import common.A;
import common.impl.B;

public class C extends D 
{
  private A delegate;

  public C ()
  {
    delegate = new B();
  }

  void doStuff() {
    delegate.doStuff(); // Call the real delegate method when doStuff is called on an isntance of C.
  }

  void doSomeRealStuffForGood() {}
}
```

Note that this is a legal OO concept, since you are following an *HAS-a* even though some could consider it a high coupling.

Otherwise if you are not tied to the `B` class, and you may drop the declare methods in there for some others, you can declare an inner class that implements the `A` interface the way you need.

### *Edit:*

Java does not support multiple inheritance, though you have provided a common contract in your `A` interface, so if you need all those methods (behavior) to be availble in your `C` class, it would be better to implement it directely and override all the interface methods.

Comment: First of all - Thanks!
That was the implementation I was talking about.
The "problem" with this implementation is that each time I add a new function to A (and implement it in B) I also need to go to C and add the the delegation for that new function, and that is the thing I was trying to avoid...
It seems that I don't really have a choice... :-)

Comment: Why not then implement the `A` interface from `C`? Look at my updated answer.